# Why does appcompat-v7:22.2.0 break ActionMode overlaying ActionBar?

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar, android-appcompat, android-actionmode

In my project I have a screen that uses action mode via:

```
mActionMode = getActivity().startActionMode(this);
```

I need this to "overlay" my action bar rather than push everything down. I achieve this using the following theme:

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
 </style>
```

So far this has worked fine when using version 22.1.0 of the appcompat library:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.0'
```

This is the result - perfect -

[image]

Recently I upgraded to version 22.2.0 of the appcompat library:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
```

Now I have the following:

[image]

As you can see, the "overlay" behaviour is completely broken. Am I missing something here?

**FYI - I am using a ToolBar in my XML layout and then using:**

```
 activity.setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
```

Comment: My first suggestion would be to go with 22.2.1.

Comment: The second is to try `windowActionModeOverlay` , rather than `android:windowActionModeOverlay` .

Comment: using windowActionModeOverlay as opposed to android:windowActionModeOverlay solved it. Put that as an answer I'll accept it. Cheers mate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `appcompat` style attribute, without the framework prefix:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
</style>
```

I'm not 100% sure, but I believe that for newer API versions it would be good to **also** keep the framework version, thus:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
</style>
```